# Submit button not works on first click

Tags: javascript, html

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvRlj.png)

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz4ul.png)

Can't figure out why submit button is not working on 1st click but working on subsequent clicks

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `onsubmit` should be in the `<form>` tag, not `<div>`. But I don't think that would explain the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code posted as picture

Answer (score 1):

Like @Barmar said, in your code, the `onsubmit` attribute is applied to the `<div>` element rather than the `<form>` element. This means that when you click the "Submit" button, it triggers the form submission, but the `sendEmail()` function is not directly invoked on the first click because the `onsubmit` event handler is attached to the `<div>`, not the form.

To rectify this, you need to change it to the following:

```html
<div>
    <form action="#" onsubmit="sendEmail()">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const fn = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('fn');
        }
    </script>
    <div >
        <form action="#" onsubmit="fn(event)">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```